# CSGO Get players items

Tags: http, steam-web-api

For a little project, I want to get a list of all CSGo player's items.
I'm using steam web API:

```
https://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetPlayerItems/v1/?key=*****&format=json&steamid=********
```

I get a HTTP 503, I'm sure that the key and the steam id exists..
The HTML:

```
<html><head><link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" title="Retour à la ligne automatique"></head><body><pre>{

}</pre></body></html>
```

Also when I try with

```
https://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v1/?key=*****&format=json&steamid=********
```

It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you entered proper Steam API key and right Steam ID

http://steamcommunity.com/dev

You can also use this link (for CS:GO):

http://steamcommunity.com/id/[YOUR_NICKNAME]/inventory/json/730/2/